# why does it say "ArgumentException: Getting control 7's position in a group with only 7 controls when doing mouseDown Aborting"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a input system from the ground up and it gave me this error. I've gone over the tutorial many time but still can't find the error.

Here's my code :

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        onFoot.Disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line (and file) does the error occur on? You should be able see this in the console log.

Comment: Sounds like this might have an explanation
https://answers.unity.com/questions/400454/argumentexception-getting-control-0s-position-in-a-1.html

Comment: for some reason the problem has disappeared